# Can `this.props.children` still be used with react-router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

The following actually can render the App component, plus one component as specified by the routes, which `this.props.children` will render in `App.js`. But is it a preferred or correct method for react-router v4?

#### Method 1

```
// in index.js

ReactDOM.render(
  (
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
      <App>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Route exact={true} path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
            <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostsShow} />
          </div>
        </Router>
      </App>
    </Provider>
  ),
  document.querySelector('#root')
);

// in App.js

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome to this awesome App</h1>
          {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Method 2

```
// in index.js  (App.js stays the same as above)

ReactDOM.render(
  (
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
      <Router>
        <App>
          <Route exact={true} path="/" component={PostsIndex} />
          <Route path="/posts/:id" component={PostsShow} />
        </App>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  ),
  document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Which is preferred depends on what you are trying to achieve. I would tend to prefer your **Method 2** since it would allow you to later add routing components inside your `App` component:

```
// in App.js
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Welcome to this awesome App</h1>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Using your **Method 1**, the `App` component is outside of the `Router` component and that would not allow you to use React Router components inside the `App` component. In general, anywhere in your app that needs routing components must be a child of the `Router` component. There might be cases where your `App` component should not use routing components but if that were the goal I would also make that explicit by adding some comments as to why `App` is outside `Router`.

It might help to think of React Router v4 as just normal React components (because they are) and then re-read the React Docs about [Composition vs Inheritance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) and [Children in JSX](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx) where they cover the use of `props.children` in great detail. In summary, `props.children` is a central part of how React works and is a recommended way of achieving composition (instead of using inheritance), so there is no reason you should avoid using it with React Router V4 where [the front page](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) states "Components are the heart of React's powerful, declarative programming model. React Router is a collection of navigational ***components that compose*** declaratively with your application." Emphasis mine.